# Jhipster jwt token management with different gateway

Tags: jwt, jhipster

How to manage/share jwt token between two Jhipster gateways when implementing Backends for Frontends pattern ?

Is a share db for the users of the two gateways will resolve this situation?

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is to share the JWT secret between your gateways and use different roles. I would not share the database as usually different gateways means different ways to authenticate.

Comment: In my case I'll like to have two gateways : one for administration tasks only (User management and so one) and the other for statistics purpose. Simple use case : admin create a user in admin gateway and the user log in the statistics one and can consume core API from there .

Comment: So please edit your question to get correct answers. You'd better use an external user management system like uaa or keycloak. You should also consider whether your use case requires all additional complexity of a microservices architecture.